# Capacitor dielectric: Is X7R a direct upgrade over 2C1?

Tags: capacitor, dielectric

I'm trying to replace a capacitor with an IECQ-CECC 2C1 Dielectric. The supplier has offered a comparable EIA X7R Dielectric. Viewing [this comparison document](http://www.radiant.su/files/images/Syfer/dielectric_information.pdf), they are largely identical. However, the X7R is not given a "Rated DC voltage applied" value.

Is this due to differing test procedures, or is it related to performance (or both?)

[image]

Comment: It's ±15%, regardless of voltage.

Comment: Why didn't they just write "± 15%" then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct to be suspicious. The voltage coefficient of 2R1/X7R is not guaranteed. It could lose 80% (or more) of its nominal value at rated voltage. You would have to check the detailed data from the manufacturer for typical values.

The worst-case voltage coefficient of 2C1 is guaranteed, so 2C1 is better (but probably larger/more expensive for the same voltage rating).

See [this](http://www.elmac.co.uk/Voltage_coefficient.pdf) reference. In this context, VCC stands for *Voltage Coefficient of Capacitance*.

> Greater than 90% loss of capacitance at rated
>   voltage is not uncommon in the general market place. But this
>   can be avoided for some parts by specifying 2C1 (BZ) or 2X1
>   (BX) dielectrics rather than standard commercial X7R (2R1).
>   These options have a more tightly controlled VCC at the
>   expense of absolute capacitance value in a given package (see
>   Figure 1 again) – although, observe that a worst-case
>   capacitance drop of 25-30% is still to be expected

Comment: Following up with this: when questioned the supplier has stated that their range of capacitors is both X7R and has a guaranteed voltage coefficient as they are broadly "Class 2" and are qualified to meet a range of standards.